# Why isn't the access check being called at all?

Tags: 8

I have the below code. I have set up the business logic and it works fine in a .module file, but not in an access controller. What am I doing wrong?

```
// nodeaccess.routing.yml

nodeaccess.people:
  path: '/user/{user}/edit'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\nodeaccess\Access\NodeaccessCustomAccessCheck::access'

// nodeaccess/src/Access/NodeaccessCustomAccessCheck.php

<?php

namespace Drupal\nodeaccess\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\Access\AccessInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

/**
 * Class NodeaccessCustomAccessCheck.
 *
 * @package Drupal\nodeaccess\Access
 */
class NodeaccessCustomAccessCheck implements AccessInterface {

  /**
   * A custom access check.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   Run access checks for the logged in user.
   */
  public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
    $current_user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    $user = User::load(explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[1]);
    if ($current_user->field_department->target_id != $user->field_department->target_id) {
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }
    return AccessResult::allowed();
    }

}
```

Comment: `I have set up the business logic and it works fine in a .module file, but not in an access controller.` - have you stepped through this with xdebug to see what the method is doing, or if it is being called?

Comment: I don't even know how to work with xdebug.

Comment: Is the `access()` function not being called, or is everything returning allowed access? Do you have other functions that are being called so we know it's not something like a namespacing issue?

Comment: access() method is not being called at all. Also, Xdebug tells me `Interface 'Drupal\Core\Routing\Access\AccessInterface' not found in /home/access/public_html/web/modules/custom/nodeaccess/src/Access/NodeaccessCustomAccessCheck.php on line 16`.

Comment: What if you try a different path than `/user/{user}/edit`? Might be a conflict with an  existing route. If you want to add an access check to a core entity route then use `hook_user_access()`. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/8.7.x

Comment: I’m supposed to do this in an access controller.

Comment: You probably need to solve the conflict with the existing route. One way or the other.

Comment: I'm trying to do this for an existing route, which is /user/{user}/edit. Am I missing something?

Comment: Entities have their own access handling system and provide the mentioned hook for custom code to hook into this system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94983/discussion-between-kartagis-and-4k4).